# Como atualizar uma coluna de dados a cada vez que alguém entra em uma página? Isso é para poder mostrar na tabela

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, table, atualização

O erro está no trecho de código onde há a variável $atualiza mais abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uso o MySQL e tenho esta tabela e o objetivo é mostrar em uma table de html os pontos de totalranking. Quando alguem ganha pontos adciono sempre os pontos no ranking e quando perdem é adcionado os pontos em menosranking.
Assim na table html eu peço para mostrar totalranking que seria "totalranking = o ranking - menosranking".
Até ai tudo bem. Mas reparem que totalranking só vive desatualizado, então fiz em PHP algo para ele atualizar a toda a coluna totalranking sempre que alguém entrasse na página, mas isso só funcionou uma única vez e não acontece as essa atualização quando alguém acessa a página.
O codigo é esse:

```html
table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Posição</th>
            <th scope="col">Nome</th>
            <th scope="col">Pontuação</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php
    $atualiza = mysqli_query($conexao, "UPDATE 'login_usuario' SET 'totalranking' = ranking - menosranking"); //deveria atualizar o banco de dados

    $query = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT usuario, totalranking FROM login_usuario ORDER BY totalranking DESC LIMIT 10"); 

    $lista = 0;
    while ($tabela = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $lista++;
    ?>

    <tbody class="table-striped"> 
        <tr>
            <th scope="row"><?php echo $lista; ?></th>
            <td><?php echo $tabela['usuario']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $tabela['totalranking']; ?></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

grato,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consegui após uns testes.

```html
"UPDATE login_usuario SET totalranking = ranking - menosranking"
```

Era problema com as aspas simples. Mas fica o questionamento e a resposta para caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar.